# How to replace relective method access by Java 1.8 functions?

Tags: java, reflection, lambda

Problem: We need to get a (String) key for different classes of objects.
For expendability we want to configure the Method to use to get the key String – instead of implementing many if-else with intanceOf…

Naive solution (with example data) is:

```
public static String getKey(Object object, Map<Class<?>, Method> keySources) {
    Method source = keySources.get(object.getClass());

    if (source == null) {
        return null;
    }

    try {
        return (String) source.invoke(object);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error at 'invoke': " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Class<?>, Method> keySources = new HashMap<>();

    try {
        keySources.put(String.class, String.class.getMethod("toString"));
        keySources.put(Thread.class, Thread.class.getMethod("getName"));
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error at 'getMethod': " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    System.out.println(getKey("test", keySources));
    System.out.println(getKey(new Thread("name"), keySources));
}
```

Desired solution would be like:

```
public static String getKey(Object object, Map<Class<?>, Function<Object, String>> keySources) {
    Function<Object, String> source = keySources.get(object.getClass());

    if (source == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return source.apply(object);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Class<?>, Function<Object, String>> keySources = new HashMap<>();

    keySources.put(String.class, String::toString);
    keySources.put(Thread.class, Thread::getName);

    System.out.println(getKey("test", keySources));
    System.out.println(getKey(new Thread("name"), keySources));
}
```

But `String::toString` is giving compilation error: `The type String does not define toString(Object) that is applicable here`

Constraints: We cannot modify the classes since they were generated.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get your code to pass compilation and run. I'm not sure why it works with lambda expressions but not with method references.

Perhaps there are better ways to do this.

```
public static <T> String getKey(T object, Map<Class<?>, Function<? extends Object, String>> keySources) 
{
    Function<T, String> source = (Function<T, String>) keySources.get(object.getClass());

    if (source == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return source.apply(object);
}

public static void main (java.lang.String[] args) throws Exception 
{
    Map<Class<?>, Function<? extends Object, String>> keySources = new HashMap<>();

    keySources.put(String.class, s -> s.toString());
    keySources.put(Thread.class, (Thread t) -> t.getName());

    System.out.println(getKey("test", keySources));
    System.out.println(getKey(new Thread("name"), keySources));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Function<Object, String>` is a function that accepts `Object`, in other words *arbitrary objects* as argument, so a function like `String::toString`, that requires its arguments to be `String` instances can’t fulfill the contract. That’s easy to fix, as you can use `Object::toString` instead, however, for `Thread::getName`, which requires the arguments to be `Thread` instances, there is no such replacement.

Since you are ensuring that the arguments are of the right type due to the map keys, you can solve this by converting each specific function to a `Function<Object,String>` that does a type cast:

```
public static <T,R> void put(Class<T> cl,
                             Function<T,R> f, Map<Class<?>,Function<Object,R>> map) {
    map.put(cl, obj -> f.apply(cl.cast(obj)));
}
public static String getKey(Object object,
                            Map<Class<?>, Function<Object, String>> keySources) {
    return keySources.getOrDefault(object.getClass(), x -> null).apply(object);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Class<?>, Function<Object, String>> keySources = new HashMap<>();

    put(String.class, String::toString, keySources);
    // or put(String.class, Function.identity(), keySources);
    put(Thread.class, Thread::getName, keySources);

    System.out.println(getKey("test", keySources));
    System.out.println(getKey(new Thread("name"), keySources));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`Function` take one parameter, which does not match the signature.

Try using `Callable` which take no parameter and return a value

Comment: there is a parameter: the object for which to get a key

Comment: that is "this", not a parameter.